# Can consumer publish events to the same ring buffer?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

Sure it can. But does that correct usage of Disruptor pattern?

My consumer prepare some data for next consumer. As far as I can see I can organize second consumer to wait for the first one. But how to pass calculated data between them?

Thanks for all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EventHandler`s do not generally claim & publish to new slots. However they are perfectly entitled to write back to the slot they are consuming from and hence have subsequent consumers see their results.

The canonical example would be un-marshalling. EventHandler1 reads the bytes from the slot, and writes the un-marhalled object to a different field in the ring buffer entry.